# About One Core for multiple app, and domains

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am currently achieve development using PHP / MySQL and CodeIgniter framework.

The goal of my development is to offer my users an "editing online tool" to manage datas (media, texts), as content management tool.

This content will then be available for broadcast (mostly through calls to mobile apps, or external websites)

So far nothing complicated.

I want to manage the "broadcast" and the "editing" on the same server, because it seems essential to have a common core, including the management of models and a part of the business layer common to the management data. But especially to avoid duplication of code.

Using CodeIgniter, it is possible to create multiple applications, I think that answers my request (what do you think?)

By cons I would have a different URL for the diffusion part and the part edition:

like : http://broadcastServer.com for broadcast requests

and : http://myEditingPrivateOnlineApp.com for users

This allows a true separation between the "apps", but also to provide other broadcast servers for large traffic.

Do you have tips or feedbacks ?

thank you

Another question in relation with first :
How on my web server ( apache 2 ) i can manage my domains for use the same shared files ( system folder, and third_party folder ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use one copy of the framework with multiple applications you must edit the `$system_path` variable in the index.php in the root of your application.  You could do something like this:

```
$system_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '../shared_folder/system';
```

To share libraries, models, helpers, config, and language files between applications you can use application packages.

You can find out how to use them at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html (scroll down to the section titled "Application Packages").

Comment: Hello, it's really a good practice for use one system folder.
The idea off third party folder is a best choice for me ( in the BackendPro for codeIgniter, Adam Price have introduce a "module"  management (CI 2.0 third party folder), and it's really useful for dev.